# How To Open A Python File With Another File Python Such That The FIRST FILE Cannot be opened By CLICKING ON IT

Tags: python, python-3.x

First I created my data saving program with python since the code was big, I divided them into 2 files
I want that the user should open the second file by first file (NOT BY CLICKING ON IT). I do not want that the user should open the second file by clicking on it. Since the first is protected with password.

Comment: please add more information

Comment: Are you thinking about encrypting some data? Or are you importing a python module?

Comment: I want to encrypt the first file, but when I open it using a new python file I want that it should not ask the password